# Comparing iterator with ptrdiff

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, templates, bubble-sort

Looking at the following code

```
template <typename Itr>
constexpr auto foo(Itr first, Itr last)
{
    for (; first != std::prev(last); std::advance(first, 1))
    {
        for (auto j{ first }; j != (std::prev(last) - first); std::advance(j, 1)) // Error here
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

In the second for loop I get the error:

```
no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type '__int64' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

I am not allowed to compare the iterator with a ptrdiff_t apperently. So how can I accomplish this task? I have tried using every cast available, to both j and the ptrdiff_t - but nothing is allowed.

The reason I need this, is because I only want the inner loop to iterate over a smaller subset of the container for each iteration of the outer loop.

An example where I need this is in the implementation of the bubble sort algorithm

```
template <typename Itr>
constexpr auto bubble_sort(Itr first, Itr last)
{
    for (; first != std::prev(last); std::advance(first, 1))
    {
        auto swapped{ false };
        for (auto j{ first }; j != (std::prev(last) - first); std::advance(j, 1))
        {
            if (*j > *std::next(j)) // Pred
            {
                std::iter_swap(j, std::next(j));
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        if (!swapped) break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to compare in `j != (std::prev(last) - first)`? You didn't really explain what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I have updated the question, please comment again if you need more info.

Comment: "a smaller subset" *which* smaller subset?

Comment: You again didn't explain exactly what you want to achieve. What is your `foo` function supposed to do?

Comment: I have updated the question once again

Comment: can you write the same loop using indices instead of iterators? That would help to explain what it is supposed to do, and perhaps it would also be already half of the solution

Comment: @Cortex Why are you trying to accomplish a silly task?!

Comment: your new code still has the same `j != (std::prev(last) - first);` but this is not only not allowed, it also makes no sense, so it is not obvious what you expect it to do.

Comment: In each iteration of the outer loop, buble sort will push the largest element to the front, after this I dont need to look at that part ever again, seeing as 'first' is incremented I subtract first from last, to ensure that I dont ever look at that part of the container again.

Comment: In that case you still want to end in the same place

Comment: @Caleth Typo, bubble sort pushes element to the end...

Comment: `j` will be an iterator.   `(std::prev(last) - first)` will be the distance between (the elements referenced by) two iterators.   Comparing the two does not even make sense.    Try describing what you are attempting to achieve by comparing them - if you can't describe that, you have no hope of solving your problem (and nobody has a hope of guessing a solution to your problem either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write the method bubble_sort for forward iterators then it can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below. Neither `ptrdiff_t` is required.

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

template <typename ForwardIterator>
void bubble_sort( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last )
{
    for ( auto sorted = last; first != last && std::next( first ) != last; last = sorted  )
    {
        for ( auto next = sorted = first, prev = next++; next != last; ++next, ++prev )
        {
            if ( *next < *prev )
            {
                std::iter_swap( prev, next );
                sorted = next;
            }
        }
    }
}

template <typename ForwardIterator, typename Comparison>
void bubble_sort( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Comparison cmp )
{
    for ( auto sorted = last; first != last && std::next( first ) != last; last = sorted  )
    {
        for ( auto next = sorted = first, prev = next++; next != last; ++next, ++prev )
        {
            if ( cmp( *next, *prev ) )
            {
                std::iter_swap( prev, next );
                sorted = next;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[N];

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    for ( auto &item : a ) item = std::rand() % N;

    for ( const auto &item : a ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    bubble_sort( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) );

    for ( const auto &item : a ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    bubble_sort( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), std::greater<>() );

    for ( const auto &item : a ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
1 5 4 4 0 9 7 3 3 1 
0 1 1 3 3 4 4 5 7 9 
9 7 5 4 4 3 3 1 1 0
```

Comment: Might want to split out the `sorted` optimisation from the iteration